# AS3 - Share a Post with an icon on FB

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

Picture icon doesn't show up on my post shared on facebook, while caption and description work ok. I am passing picture url directly as string, is that correct?

```
var params:Object = {   
caption: 'Caption text',
description: 'Description text',
picture: 'https://....../my-image.png' };
```

Comment: HTTPS URLs are sometimes problematic in this regard. If your picture is available via an HTTP URL as well, then I’d suggest you try using that first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568970/posting-message-on-facebook-wall-via-flash-actionscript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568970/posting-message-on-facebook-wall-via-flash-actionscript